# select 2 widget validation with j query in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

so i have written a code for select field and i am using yii2 here is my code

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'primaryfield')->widget(Select2::classname(), ['data' 
   => $listData, 
   'options' => ['placeholder'=>'Select', 'multiple' => 
   false,'required'=>true], 'pluginOptions' => ['tags' => false, 'tokenSeprators' 
  => [',', ' '], 'maximumInputLength' => 20], ],])->label(false); ?>
```

i want to validate it by using jquery validate plugin i have tried so far validation rules

```
$('form').validate({


errorClass:'help-block help-block-error',

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

if(element.attr("name") == "TestModel[primaryfield]" )
{
    error.insertAfter(".error_message2");
}
else
      error.insertAfter(element);
 },

       rules: {
    'TestModel[email]': {
    required:true,
   email: true 
  },

 'TestModel[name]':
 {
  required:true,
},

'TestModel[primaryfield]':
 {
   required:true
 }

 },
```

my email and name getting validated but select2 field(primary field is not getting validate ) i want to apply validation rules only if anyone can give me solutions

Answer (score 0):

With Yii2, You just declare rules in Model. Then,

In your template, enable "enableClientValidation" option of AcitveForm as below:

```
<?php $form = \kartik\form\ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'ajax-contact-form'
    ]
]); ?>
```

With Select2 Widget, it's not enough. So I have to using javascript as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on("select2:close", function (e) {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            var formGroup = $(this).parent().parent();
            formGroup.addClass('has-error');
            $('.help-block:first', formGroup).html('Please choose one partner!')
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the result on form: 
[image]
My select2 HTML structure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but its not working for select2 widget

Comment: @Sneh:  I've just edit my answer. It works fine on my project. Good luck!